# Neither gluPerspective nor glOrtho have any effect

Tags: c++, opengl

EDIT........ So I've gotten rid of all the crap and just have an SSCE now (hopefully I understand what one is now). For anyone who hasn't seen this problem already, I want to maintain the aspect ratio when resizing, but the window behaves as though I had commented out anything to do with resizing (it stretches). I have checked the projection matrix along all points and it changes at the points you'd expect and stays the same at the points you'd expect.

I stripped out the stuff that relies on other files, so it should compile for you, except the shader files, I will post their code too (they are very short). I'm sorry it doesn't look very nicely formatted, it is hard to keep the formatting having to put 4 spaces in front of most of the lines.

The wire cube does not appear by the way. But when copying verbatim my first answerer's suggestion and compiling it, it does appear. Not sure if that is related to my problem.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC

#include "glew.h"
#include "glut.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//#include "TgaParser.h"
//#include "Vertex.h"
//#include "ObjParser.h"
//#include "Car.h"
//#include "Floor.h"
//#include "BitmapParser.h"
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glut32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32s.lib")

/*GLOBALS*/
int g_ScreenWidth       = 800;
int g_ScreenHeight      = 800;
int g_Program           = 0;
int g_PositionHandle    = 0;
int g_TextureCoordhandle = 0;
int g_ModelMatrixHandle = 0;

//Car* g_pCar = 0;
//Floor* g_pFloor = 0;

void error(char * error)
{
    printf(error);
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}

static void checkGlError(const char* op) 
{
    for (GLint error = glGetError(); error; error
        = glGetError()) 
    {
        const GLubyte* sError = gluErrorString(error);
        printf("Shader error %s\n",sError);
    }
}

GLuint loadShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* pSource) 
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader) 
    {
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &pSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        GLint compiled = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        checkGlError("createVertexShader");
        if (!compiled) 
        {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            if (infoLen) 
            {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(infoLen);
                if (buf) 
                {
                    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, buf);
                    printf(buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
                glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

GLuint createProgram(const char* pVertexSource, const char* pFragmentSource) 
{
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, pVertexSource);
    checkGlError("createVertexShader");
    if (!vertexShader) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint pixelShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, pFragmentSource);
    if (!pixelShader) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    g_Program=program;
    if (program) 
    {
        glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        glLinkProgram(program);
        GLint linkStatus = GL_FALSE;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
        if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE) 
        {
            GLint bufLength = 0;
            glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufLength);
            if (bufLength) 
            {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(bufLength);
                if (buf) 
                {
                    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, bufLength, NULL, buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
            }
            glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
    }
    return program;
}

void forward_display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60, (GLfloat)g_ScreenWidth/(GLfloat)g_ScreenHeight, 0.1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //gluLookAt(0, -0.5, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0);

    //glPushMatrix ();
    //glRotatef(timeGetTime()*0.05,0,1,0);
    //g_pCar->Draw(g_ModelMatrixHandle, g_PositionHandle, g_TextureCoordhandle);
    //glPopMatrix ();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -2);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glRotatef( 45, 1, 1, 0 );
    glutWireCube(1);


    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void forward_animate()
{
    forward_display();
}

/*Reads in all of the data contents automatically allocating memory for the content*/
char* readFileData (char * fileName)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName,"r"); 
    if (fp==0)
    {
        error("Why is all rum gone!!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sz = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    char * data = new char[sz+1];
    memset(data,0,sz+1);
    fread(data,1,sz,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return data;
}

void init()
{
    char  * vertexShaderBuffer = readFileData("../resources/shaders/IntroToShaders.vs");
    char  * pixelShaderBuffer  = readFileData("../resources/shaders/IntroToShaders.ps");

    g_Program = createProgram (vertexShaderBuffer, pixelShaderBuffer);

    //We have finished  compiling the shader now delete the char arrays with the source code
    delete [] vertexShaderBuffer;
    delete [] pixelShaderBuffer;

    g_PositionHandle        = glGetAttribLocation(g_Program, "vPosition");
    g_TextureCoordhandle    = glGetAttribLocation(g_Program, "vTextureCoord");
    g_ModelMatrixHandle     = glGetUniformLocation(g_Program, "modelview_matrix");

    if (g_PositionHandle == -1)
    {
        printf("g_PositionHandle is bad\n");
    }

    if (g_TextureCoordhandle == -1)
    {
        printf("g_TextureCoordhandle is bad\n");
    }

    if (g_ModelMatrixHandle == -1)
    {
        printf("g_ModelMatrixHandle is bad\n");
    }
    glUseProgram(g_Program);


    //g_pCar = new Car();
    //g_pCar->Initialise ();
    //g_pFloor = new Floor ();
    //g_pFloor->Initialise ();

    //g_pCar->InitTextures();
    //g_pFloor->InitTextures ();

    //g_pCar->LoadTextures ();
    //g_pFloor->LoadTextures ();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    g_ScreenWidth = w;
    g_ScreenHeight = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutInitWindowSize(g_ScreenWidth, g_ScreenHeight);
    glutCreateWindow("Assignment 1");
    glewInit();

    init ();

    glutDisplayFunc(forward_display);
    glutIdleFunc(forward_animate);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    glutMainLoop();
    /*
    DONT DO THINGS HERE
    */
    return 0;
}
```

IntroToShaders.ps:

```
varying  vec2 vTexCoord; 
uniform sampler2D myTexture;
void main (void)  
{  
   gl_FragColor =  texture2D(myTexture, vTexCoord);     
}
```

IntroToShaders.vs:

```
attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying  vec2 vTexCoord; 
uniform  mat4 modelview_matrix;

void main(void)  
{     
   vTexCoord =  vTextureCoord;
   gl_Position =  modelview_matrix*vec4(vPosition,1.0);
}
```

Comment: -1: Similar to what you have is *not* what you have. Posting working code isn't helping us find the problem in your *not working* code. We need to see an SSCCE of *your* code which exhibits the problem you're having.

Comment: "it is hard to keep the formatting having to put 4 spaces in front of most of the lines."...if you're using Visual Studio/Eclipse/Netbeans for editing just set 4-space tabs in the options, select your entire program, and hit tab.  It should indent everything by 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks genpfault!!! I will do that next time I post a question :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you hoped to accomplish without a `glutInit()` call.

Try this:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void forward_display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective(60, w / h, 0.1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -2 );

    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glRotatef( 45, 1, 1, 0 );
    glutWireCube( 1 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("Intro to shading");

    glutDisplayFunc(forward_display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** Given the code in (as of this writing) [the most recent revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16238706/5), give this a shot:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdio>

/*GLOBALS*/
int g_Program = 0;
int g_ProjectionMatrixHandle = 0;
int g_ModelMatrixHandle = 0;

static void checkGlError(const char* op) 
{
    for (GLint error = glGetError(); error; error
        = glGetError()) 
    {
        const GLubyte* sError = gluErrorString(error);
        printf("Shader error %s\n",sError);
    }
}

GLuint loadShader(GLenum shaderType, const char* pSource) 
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if (shader) 
    {
        glShaderSource(shader, 1, &pSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(shader);
        GLint compiled = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        checkGlError("createVertexShader");
        if (!compiled) 
        {
            GLint infoLen = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);
            if (infoLen) 
            {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(infoLen);
                if (buf) 
                {
                    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLen, NULL, buf);
                    printf(buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
                glDeleteShader(shader);
                shader = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return shader;
}

GLuint createProgram(const char* pVertexSource, const char* pFragmentSource) 
{
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, pVertexSource);
    checkGlError("createVertexShader");
    if (!vertexShader) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint pixelShader = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, pFragmentSource);
    if (!pixelShader) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    g_Program=program;
    if (program) 
    {
        glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        glLinkProgram(program);
        GLint linkStatus = GL_FALSE;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
        if (linkStatus != GL_TRUE) 
        {
            GLint bufLength = 0;
            glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &bufLength);
            if (bufLength) 
            {
                char* buf = (char*) malloc(bufLength);
                if (buf) 
                {
                    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, bufLength, NULL, buf);
                    free(buf);
                }
            }
            glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
    }
    return program;
}

void forward_display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective(60, w / h, 0.1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -2);

    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glRotatef( 45, 1, 1, 0 );

    GLfloat projection[16];
    glGetFloatv( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( g_ProjectionMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, projection );

    GLfloat modelview[16];
    glGetFloatv( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( g_ModelMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, modelview );

    glutWireCube(1);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void forward_timer( int extra )
{
    glutTimerFunc( 16, forward_timer, 0 );
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

#define GLSL(version, shader) "#version " #version "\n" #shader

const char * vertexShaderBuffer = GLSL
(
    120,
    uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
    uniform mat4 modelview_matrix;

    varying vec4 vColor; 

    void main(void)  
    {
        vColor = gl_Color;
        gl_Position = projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * gl_Vertex;
    }
);

const char * pixelShaderBuffer = GLSL
(
    120,
    varying vec4 vColor; 
    void main (void)  
    {  
        gl_FragColor = vColor;
    }
);

void init()
{
    g_Program = createProgram (vertexShaderBuffer, pixelShaderBuffer);
    glUseProgram(g_Program);

    g_ProjectionMatrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(g_Program, "projection_matrix");
    if (g_ProjectionMatrixHandle == -1)
    {
        printf("g_ProjectionMatrixHandle is bad\n");
    }

    g_ModelMatrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(g_Program, "modelview_matrix");
    if (g_ModelMatrixHandle == -1)
    {
        printf("g_ModelMatrixHandle is bad\n");
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("Assignment 1");
    glewInit();

    init ();

    glutDisplayFunc(forward_display);
    glutTimerFunc( 0, forward_timer, 0 );

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding glutInit like you suggested while leaving everything else the same, did not work. Then I tried making it the same as yours (got rid of idlefunc and reshape func, doing reshape in the drawing function) and still the same, only my car no longer rotates.

Comment: I also tried drawing the wire cube instead of the car but nothing shows up. I think this is because of using shaders maybe?

Comment: Regarding your recent edit, there is a lot of your code I am not familiar with. Also I think it is intended for OpenGL 3 when I am only using OpenGL 2 - I tried compiling the code. What is the basic intention of your code, i.e., what is it in my program that does not work and how does this fix it? If I can understand that then maybe I can fix my code myself within OpenGL2. Thank you for your time.

Comment: That code should just be using the OpenGL 2.1 feature set.  What compilation errors are you getting?  I'll try to whip up a new version that relies more on the code you posted.

Comment: Your code still won't work for me (unresolved external symbols about glew functions) but it doesn't matter, I found my problem. I went through your code and implemented anything that was different. The one that fixed it was having a projection matrix handle and passing that to the shader. It probably would have been a lot less work for you if you had seen it was missing and just told me but thanks for giving me enough material to figure it out myself :-) I also think how you're passing colours to the shader will allow me to draw shapes. Once I learn how shaders work I can fix that aspect too.

Answer (score 0):

gluPerspective does not work when you have shaders, unless you pass the projection matrix handle to the shader.

So have a global int g_ProjectionMatrixHandle = 0 at the beginning with your other globals.

Then get the handle in your init phase:

```
g_ProjectionMatrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(g_Program, "projection_matrix");
```

Then send the handle to the shader in your drawing phase:

```
GLfloat p[16];
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, p);
glUniformMatrix4fv(g_ProjectionMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, p);
```

Then collect the handle in the shader and use it:

```
attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTextureCoord;
varying  vec2 vTexCoord; 
uniform  mat4 modelview_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

void main(void)  
{     
   vTexCoord =  vTextureCoord;
   gl_Position =  projection_matrix * modelview_matrix * vec4(vPosition,1.0);
}
```

I will also figure out why I can't draw shapes soon and edit this answer later on in case anyone else is having problems.

By the way if you are just drawing regular shapes (lines, polygons etc) instead of arrays for coordinates and textures, and are using shaders for some reason, refer to genpfault's code for your shader.